# ASP.NET Ajax doesnt call Url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

Ajax doesnt seem to be working on my View. I simplified my problem down to having a button call a controller method via ajax. The result is the same html of the view is being appended to the div. Looking through the debugger, the same **GetEventForm** url is called and not **TestAjax**

**Button in GetEventForm.cshtml**

`<input type="button" id="btn" value="Test Ajax" class="btn-sm"/>`

`<div id="rule"> </div>`

Ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btn').on('click', function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                Url: '@Url.Action("TestAjax","Events")',
                success: function(result) { $("#rule").html(result); }
            });
        });
     });
 </script>
```

**Controller**

```
    public string TestAjax()
    {
        return "Response string from Controller!";
    }
```

[Before Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXk04.jpg)

[After Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWjRS.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try lowercase "url":

$.ajax({...

```
    url : '...'

    });
```

Comment: This is obviously the answer. It's just one of those days. Thank you.